# Text Based Games in python: moving room to room with a loop

Tags: python, string, loops, if-statement

I'm having trouble figuring out why this code won't run... I'm having this issue:

[image]

```py
def show_instructions():        #print a main menu and the commands
    print("Murder Mystery: Knives Out")
    print("Investigate the murder, collect evidence, and find the killer!")
    print("Collect 6 items to narrow down who the killer is, failure to do so will allow the killer to escape.")
    print("Use Move commands: go North, go South, go East, go West")
    print("Collect evidence: get 'item name'")

rooms = {'Walkway' : {'South' : 'Bar', 'North' : 'Kitchen', 'East' : 'Library', 'West' : 'Bedroom' },'Bedroom' : {'item' : 'Torn Fabric', 'East' : 'Walkway'},'Library' : {'Item' : 'a clue from a guest', 'North' : 'Office', 'Item' : 'Gun', 'West' : 'Walkway'},'Bar' : {'Item' : 'Whiskey', 'East' : 'Dining Room', 'Item': 'Bloody Steak Knife'},'Kitchen' : {'Item': 'Steak Knife', 'South': 'Walkway', 'East': 'Wine Cellar',},'Wine Cellar' :{'West': 'Kitchen', 'Item' : 'Murderer'} #villain}state = 'Walkway'def get_new_state(state,direction):new_state = statefor i in rooms:if i == state:if direction in rooms[i]:new_state=rooms[i][direction]return new_state

def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']

def show_instructions():
    print("Murder Mystery Game: Knives Out")
    print("Investigate the murder, collect evidence, and find the killer!")

print("Collect 6 items to narrow down who the killer is, failure to do so will allow the killer to escape.")
print("Use Move commands: go North, go South, go East, go West")
print("Collect evidence: get 'item name'")

show_instructions()

Inventory=[]
Items = ['Torn Fabric', 'Whiskey', 'Bloody Steak Knife', 'Clue from Guest', 'Gun','Steak Knife']

while(1):
    print('You are in ',state)
    print('Inventory:',Inventory)
    Item = get_item(state)
    print('You see a ',Item)
    print('--------------------')
    if Item == 'Murderer':
        print("BANG! You got shot by the murderer... GAME OVER!")
        exit(0)

direction = input('Enter your move: ')
if direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South':
    direction=direction[3:]
    
new_state=get_new_state(state,direction)
if new_state == state:
    print("There's a wall on that direction... enter another direction!")
else:
    state=new_stateel

if direction==str('get '+Item):
    if Item in Inventory:
        print("There are no new items, go to a different room....")
    else:
        Inventory.append(Item)
else:
    print("Invalid input or move or Item")

if len(Inventory)==6:
    print("Congratulations! You have gathered all of the evidence and caught the Murderer!")
    print("The Police arrive and have the Murderer in custody, great job!")
    print("GAME OVER")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    exit(0)
```

Comment: I apologize, it code blocked all of them separately

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Check to see if ```rooms[state]``` actually has a key 'Item'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the room 'Walkway' is missing the 'Item' key.